# How to search app in Azure Active Directory based only on object id?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps

I have created a Logic App and enabled 'Identity' on it with respect to the specific tenant I am connected to (I only have one), that provided me with an object id. Now I went to Azure Active Directory (the same tenant) and in the 'Enterprise applications' tried to search this id but no result. Also the hint in the search box specifically asks to either enter application name or application id -- it doesn't say anything about 'object id'. The logic app I have created doesn't show any 'application id' associated with it. So, how to ensure that the logic app shows up in the AAD?

Comment: Is it a single tenant APP or Multi tenant APP ? In which tenant is this APP registered ?

Comment: our organization has only single tenant

Answer (score 0):

Change the filter in Enterprise applications to *All applications*, then search with your Logic App name.
The system-assigned managed identity should have the same name as your app.